# Port number needed after domain name

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have followed along a digital ocean tutorial to deploy my node.js app onto VPS. Everything is working, but instead of reaching the app from myDomain.com, it's only available through myDomain.com:3700. myDomain.com only shows "Success! Virtual host is set up!"

/etc/nginx.sites-available/default:

```
server {
    listen 3700;

    server_name myDomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Oddly, if I change it to:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name myDomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3700;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

and enter sudo nginx -s reload, nothing changes.

in my node app, I have:

```
...
var port = 3700;
...
```

Comment: Can you post more of your node app, it would be helpful to see what you're doing with `port`.

Comment: If you change the listened port reload doesn't work, try to restart instead.